# Why do old Asp.Net webforms projects have a different properties dialog in Visual Studio 2010 than new projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I maintain a couple of legacy ASP.Net webforms solutions, that I have upgraded to use .Net 4.

However, they appear to be different in Visual Studio 2010, than other projects. If I open properties for one of the web projects in the solution, it looks like this:

[image]

The old-school dialog from previous versions. No fancy publishing and other neat "new" stuff.

What is going on here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have created a New Web Site...

You're looking for Web Application it sounds like. Go to File > New > Project..., and ASP.NET Web Application is under there. You may also want ASP.NET Empty Web Application as it doesn't have some auto-generated junk in it.

Comment: You are right. And it seems there is no conversion path. You need to create a new empty web app and manually copy stuff over.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx